# If A is mapping-reducible to B and is not mapping-reducible to co-B, is A Turing-reducible to co-B?

Tags: computability, reductions

> If $A \leq_m B$ and $A$ is not mapping reducible to $co\text{-}B$, then $A \leq_T co\text{-}B$.

Is this true?

My intuition is false even if we can find some special case to make it true such as $A=B=co\text{-}A_{TM}$. However, I still can't find a counterexample.

Could anyone give me a little hint?

Comment: Can you solidify your intiuition? *Why* does it feel wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $A \leq_m B$ then there is a computable function $f$ such that $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in B$ iff it is not the case that $f(x) \in \text{co-}B$. Can you use this to Turing-reduce $A$ to $\text{co-}B$?

Comment: If the function `f` is computable, so it can be computed by a Turing machine, so, is the Truing reduction more restrict than mapping reduction?

Comment: @emab Not at all. Turing reductions are *less* strict than mapping reductions.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Thanks. Should I construct an oracle Turing machine of $co-B$ to decide $A$? This is the only way I could come up to prove the Turing reducibility.

Comment: @user3273554 This is the *definition* of Turing reducibility.